# Trace WPF System.Windows.ResourceDictionary warning Resource not found

Tags: c#, wpf, debugging, trace, resourcedictionary

I get below error on output window. I can't find what is the problem?

> System.Windows.ResourceDictionary Warning: 9 : Resource not found;
>   ResourceKey='17' System.Windows.ResourceDictionary Warning: 9 :
>   Resource not found; ResourceKey='#FF000000';
>   ResourceKey.HashCode='51639504';
>   ResourceKey.Type='System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush'
>   System.Windows.ResourceDictionary Warning: 9 : Resource not found;
>   ResourceKey='17' System.Windows.ResourceDictionary Warning: 9 :
>   Resource not found; ResourceKey='#FF000000';
>   ResourceKey.HashCode='51639504';
>   ResourceKey.Type='System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush'
>   System.Windows.ResourceDictionary Warning: 9 : Resource not found;
>   ResourceKey='17'

How to find what's error???

Comment: Where are your resources located ?

Comment: without your xaml we can't do anything!

Comment: It's not related to our xaml. I using Prism and some 3rd party control. My project very larg and can't upload files. I search a way to Trace this type of warning.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with WinDBG you can break the process execution into the debugger on debug output and examine the callstack.

To do so in WinDBG, attach to your process and go to Debug->Event filters

Find a line that says "Debugee output" and click on it
On the right click "Enabled" under execution

Type g in the command line to run the debugger and when it breaks on the correct output, use kb to print unmanaged callstack or
.loadby sos clr
!clrstack
to print managed callstack

Comment: Thanks, i will check and keep you inform

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to search your entire solution for a string like `{StaticResource 17}`, `{DynamicResource 17}` or `{x:Static 17}`. You cannot *trace* something like that. There's some faulty xaml you have to fix.

Comment: I already search this, but not found! I think it related to 3rd-party control, but i want to find it